# How to call jQuery for product option dropdown onchange event in Shopify?

Tags: jquery, shopify

I am new to Shopify.

I want to change product main image `onchange` event of color dropdown option of product. My color dropdown name is `name="properties[Color]"`.

I have write this code to change image by selecting color from color drop down

```
jQuery('select[name="properties[Color]"]').change(function()
    {
        var option = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').val();
        var color = option.replace(" ", "_");            
        alert(color);

        jQuery('#elevatezoom_gallery img').each(function () {
            var src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
            if (src.indexOf(color) >= 0){
               alert(src);

                jQuery("#elevatezoom_big").attr('src', src.replace('_compact', '_grande'));
                jQuery("#elevatezoom_big").attr('data-zoom-image', src.replace('_compact', '_grande'));
                jQuery(".zoomWindowContainer div").css('background-image','url('+src.replace('_compact', '_grande')+')');
            }
        });
    });
```

but jQuery is not run on my shopify store. I print alert message to check that, is jQuery working or not but no alert comes.

Please help me how I can call jquery on color dropdown change.

My full code is this

```
<script>

var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {


   // ---- by dkrao2008@gmail.com - start - (for color image on change color from dropdown) ------//    
   jQuery('select[name="properties[Color]"]').change(function()
    {
        var option = jQuery(this).find('option:selected').val();
        var color = option.replace(" ", "_");            
        //alert(color);

        jQuery('#elevatezoom_gallery img').each(function () {
            var src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
            if (src.indexOf(color) >= 0){
                //alert(src);

                jQuery("#elevatezoom_big").attr('src', src.replace('_compact', '_grande'));
                jQuery("#elevatezoom_big").attr('data-zoom-image', src.replace('_compact', '_grande'));
                jQuery(".zoomWindowContainer div").css('background-image','url('+src.replace('_compact', '_grande')+')');
            }
        });
    });
    // ---- by dkrao2008@gmail.com - end - (for color image on change color from dropdown) ------//


    if ( variant && variant.available ) {
        jQuery('#add-to-cart').removeAttr('disabled').removeClass('disabled'); // remove unavailable class from add-to-cart button, and re-enable button

        if( variant.price < variant.compare_at_price ){
            jQuery('#product_price .price').html('<span class="money">' + Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "{{ shop.money_format }}") + '</span><span class="money compare-at-price">' + Shopify.formatMoney(variant.compare_at_price, "{{ shop.money_format }}") + '</span>');
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#product_price .price').html('<span class="money">' + Shopify.formatMoney(variant.price, "{{ shop.money_format }}") + '</span>');
        };
    }
    else {
        jQuery('#add-to-cart').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled', 'disabled'); // set add-to-cart button to unavailable class and disable button

        var message = variant ? "Sold Out" : "Unavailable";
        jQuery('#product_price .price').text(message);
    };

    if (variant && variant.featured_image) {
        var originalImage = $("#elevatezoom_big");
        var newImage = variant.featured_image;
        var element = originalImage[0];

        Shopify.Image.switchImage(newImage, element, function (newImageSizedSrc, newImage, element) {
            jQuery('#elevatezoom_big').attr('src', newImageSizedSrc).attr('data-zoom-image', newImageSizedSrc);

            jQuery("#elevatezoom_gallery a").each(function(){
                if ( jQuery(this).attr('data-zoom-image').replace(/\?v=.*/ , '') == newImageSizedSrc.replace(/\?v=.*/ , '') ) {
                    jQuery(this).trigger('click');
                };
            });
        });
    };


};

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    new Shopify.OptionSelectors( "product-select",
    {
        product: {{ product | json }},
        onVariantSelected: selectCallback,
        enableHistoryState: true 
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure that the `onchange` event is fired inside the callvack function of `OptionSelectors`. This is because once you change the select the function `OptionSelectors` is fired up and it calls the callback function, where you have the `onchange` event, but since the select is already changed it won't fire. It needs to be tested but that's my logic at least.

Comment: No, i was working, there was a jQuery version conflict so that onchange event not fired up. Now i have added new version of jQuery and pull out my function out side of callback function. It is working but only first time when i reload it it not working. Product option is coming from a third part app in Shopify. may be this is causing issue.

Comment: check here http://www.verbalshirts.com/products/irun-baby?variant=6309865989 when you open this my code is working but after reload it not working.